# Seeing more than 10 test examples in Tensoboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I am running the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) on a batch of 1000 labeled images, 80 of which I kept for testing.

This is being done using the provided `train.py` and `eval.py` scripts, and also using [one](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config) of the pipelines provided in the repo.

After I get `train.py` and `eval.py` running, I run [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) to monitor the training progress. However, when I go to the *Image* tab, I only find 10 out of the 80 examples I saved for training.

Is there any way to **force Tensorboard to use all the provided examples**?

Answer (score 1):

You can change this by setting num_visualizations to the desired max number in the pipeline.config file in the eval_config block

if you have the config loaded:

```
pipeline_config.eval_config.num_visualizations = 50
```

or in the file:

```
eval_config {            
  num_visualizations: 50 
  ...
}
```

Full example, reading / changing / writing

```
# Read source model pipeline config
pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(SOURCE_PIPELINE_CONFIG_FILE_PATH, "r") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    proto_str = f.read()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)  

#Set the parameter
pipeline_config.eval_config.num_visualizations = 50

#Change other parameters here

# Save adjusted pipeline config to own model
config_text = text_format.MessageToString(pipeline_config)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(TARGET_PIPELINE_CONFIG_FILE_PATH, "wb") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    f.write(config_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer to myself.

The answer is **no; only 10 evaluation images can be seen in Tensorboard at the same time**.

To test more images one would have to export the model at a given checkpoint and write a script for running inferences using that model over a set of images.

It would certainly not be automatic, in real time and as comfortable as it is seeing Tensorboard do all of this for you, but it's a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get this to work in Tensorboard 1.11.0 by editing the object_detection/protos/eval.proto file, then re-running protoc (see the Tensorflow docs). For example, this line in eval.proto would enable 100 examples (instead of the default 10):

**optional uint32 num_visualizations = 1 [default=100];**

This probably has an impact on system memory, browser performance, eval performance, etc.. so use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Inline replace and rerun protoc command before you train.

```
sed -i 's/uint32 num_visualizations = 1 \[default = 10\]/uint32 num_visualizations = 1 \[default = 30\]/' /content/models/research/object_detection/protos/eval.proto

cd /content/models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder, since you change the default, can't this be passed/overwritten via pipeline?